# If a lever fixed at one end is laid across a scale, and you stand on the other end of the lever, what will the scale read?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, torque

Let's imagine we have a long lever fixed to the ground at one end by a hinge. We lay this lever across a scale with the scale placed a distance d1 away from the hinge, then tear it. Then a person stands on the end of the lever opposite from the hinge, a distance d2 away from the scale.

```
                                    o
                                   -|-
                                   / \
  o-----------------------------------
  ^       d1        ^       d2
hinge             Scale
```

Let's say that the person's weight is normally x (as measured by the scale when they stand directly on it). What will the scale read when they stand d1 distance away from the scale?

As a follow up, I'd like to imagine a similar scenario:
We take our setup from above, but now we weld the lever to the scale and cut off the hinge and the rest of the lever on that side. So now we just have:

```
                  o
                 -|-
                 / \
  ------------------
  ^       d
Scale
```

In this scenario, the person is standing a distance d away from the scale. What will their weight read in this scenario?

**EDIT**
I think we can ignore the second example.
Upon further thinking, the second example doesn't make much sense. A scale measures normal force, and in the second example, there doesn't appear to be any normal force, only a rotational force (torque). I could imagine that the second example might actually cause the scale to read 0 (half the sensors would be lifted and the other half would be pressed down).

Comment: You'll run into issues with the physical realization of the second scenario. In the ideal case, the lever touches the scale at one single point, just like the ideal hinge in the first scenario. But if that's the case, there's nothing at all holding the lever up, since it can rotate freely about its only point of contact. If the scale itself can hold the lever up, you have a more complicated interaction between the scale and the lever, since they cannot only touch at one point.

Comment: cool diagrams o\-<

Comment: A lever setup must have a load, a fulcrum (pivot), and a force.

Comment: Good point @NuclearWang. I think I see what you mean. I think in the second case, (if we assume the scale is welded to the floor), there is only a rotational force on the scale.... (and how does a scale measure a rotational force??). So I could imagine that perhaps in the second case the scale might show 0 if there is a sensor in each corner of the scale (the two away from the person would be lifted and reading a negative force, and the two on the side closer to the person would be depressed and reading an equal positive force).

Comment: @AdrianHoward, I think the second example definitely cannot fit a lever setup. But what about the first setup? Is it possible to have the first setup somehow map to a lever setup with a load, a fulcrum, and a force? I'm thinking that perhaps the load could be the weight of the person, the fulcrum could be the scale, and the force could be the normal force exerted by the hinge? But my question extends a bit beyond the classical lever setup, because I am asking for the resulting force on the fulcrum in this example (the scale!)

Comment: I'm a lever, not a fighter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case you have a class 2 lever which has a pivot (fulcrum) at one end, a force at the other end, and the load in between. The leverage applied to the load is a ratio of the distances of the load and the force from the pivot. If the scale is in the center, as it  appears to be in your diagram, the scale will read twice the man's weight as he is twice as far from the piivot as the scale is. The second case does not have a pivot so it cannot apply leverage. You should read this article, it should have all the info you need; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever

Answer (score 0):

In the second case: if the scale is a foot wide and d is 100ft, it will break. If d is 5ft you have a setup similar to the first case, which you should diagram.

Answer (score 0):

These can be solved using equations for rotational and translational equilibrium of the rod.(considering rod to be massless)

### Case 1

Torque equations about hinge for rotational equilibrium. N is normal force applied by scale.
$$mg(d_1+d_2)=N.d_1$$
$$N=mg\frac{d_1+d_2}{d_1}$$

### Case 2

The net force in vertical direction must be zero.
$\implies N_{net}=mg$

This solution is for an ideal case , but it must hold true for a real case too as the conditions for equilibrium will be the same.